# How to use COUNTIF with multiple conditions & matching columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

Excel Countif Multiple Conditions Formula

I'm trying to count if column b matches column c unless column b=1 and column c=1

| Total Packages | # of Open Packages |
| --- | --- |
| 26 | 1 |
| 31 | 1 |
| 25 | 2 |
| 23 | 1 |
| 19 | 1 |
| 22 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 14 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 22 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 14 | 1 |

I have tried

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$11, ">1", $B$2:$C$11, "$B2=$C2").
```

I have also tried

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B49732 = C2:C49732))
```

but this doesn't fully work/is missing a piece as well.

I want to create a cell
that can count the above^

Answer (score 2):

Add a condition to your `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B49732=C2:C49732)*(B2:B49732<>1))
```

Answer (score 2):

A formula you can use would be

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$B$14=$C$2:$C$14))-SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$14=1)*($C$2:$C$14=1))
```

This will first get all the rows that are equal to each other then subtract the rows that are both equal to 1